# how to read 5 integers from a user and returns an array with those numbers?

Tags: java, eclipse

This is my attempt to figure out my problem. the array of those 5 numbers should be in order.

```
System.out.println("input 1 number");
int 1 = kb.nextInt();
System.out.println("input 1 number");
int 2 = kb.nextInt();
System.out.println("input 1 number");
int 3 = kb.nextInt();
System.out.println("input 1 number");
int 4 = kb.nextInt();
System.out.println("input 1 number");
int 5 = kb.nextInt();

int []arr = new int[1,2,3,4,5];
```

Comment: This is a totally incorrect use of the language. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/. Specifically, look through the tutorials on variable declaration and arrays.

Answer (score 4):

This does what you want:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in); // Define System input using a Scanner.

int[] nums = new int[5]; // Define a new array of size 5, with the type 'int'

for(int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) { // Loop 5 times
  System.out.println("Enter a number: "); // Ask the user for a number.
  nums[i] = in.nextInt(); // Read the next int from the console.
}

Arrays.sort(nums); // Sort the numbers in ascending order.
```

You might want to look at some Java syntax tutorials, you seem to have very little understanding of the syntax. Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [array](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) tutorial. There are too many ways to create and assign/initialize an array.

Once you have read and store five int values into variables then you can initialize an array like:

```
int []ar={var1,var2,var3,var4,var5};
```

Another way to create an array of five elements is:

```
int []ar=new int[5];
ar[0]=kb.nextInt();
...
```

You can use `java.util.Arrays.sort()` method to sort an array elements.